# What are the controller tags available in play2.1?

Tags: playframework-2.1

Is there any documentation I can refer to get the complete details about the controller tags like "@input" available in play framework 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all tags in the API, with a little doc:

- [API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.package)
- [Sources](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper)